# Docker mount volume overrides data in folder

Tags: docker

I might miss something really obvious. A Symfony app is living in a container in /atom/src.

```
docker@localhost:~/atom-docker$ sudo docker-compose exec atom ls /atom/src/
CONTRIBUTING.md  cache            favicon.ico      plugins
COPYRIGHT        composer.json    images           qubit_dev.php
Dockerfile       composer.lock    index.php        robots.txt
LICENSE          config           init             symfony
README.md        css              js               test
SECURITY.md      data             lib              vendor
apps             docker           log
build.xml        ead.dtd          phpunit.xml
```

When trying to mount a volume called uploads into the folder:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:

...

 atom:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-atom
    command: "fpm"
    ...
    volumes:
      - uploads:/atom/src/uploads
    restart: on-failure

 nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    ...
    depends_on:
      - "atom"
    volumes:
      - uploads:/atom/src/uploads
    restart: on-failure


volumes:
  ...
  uploads:
    driver: "local"

...
```

the uploads folder does not get mounted inside the path but all Data in /atom/src get replaced

```
docker@localhost:~/atom-docker$ sudo docker-compose exec atom ls /atom/src/
uploads
```

What is wrong with my volume definition?

Comment: I doubt the issue is in the snippet you posted. That looks alright. Perhaps in the way the named volume `uploads` is defined?

Comment: Thanks, @cornuz I've edited the question and added the two services that share the volume and the volume definition. does this look correct?

Comment: I still don't see any issue. Does `sudo docker-compose exec nginx ls /atom/src/` do the same?

Comment: unfortunately yes. same on nginx

Comment: Try create a `folder` named `uploads` in the same position of the `docker-compose.yml`, and change the docker-compose to  this `- ./uploads:/atom/src/uploads`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but I think it can give you some useful feedback and I couldn't have written this in a comment.

I tried a minimal reproducible test that should be equivalent to your case:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

 atom:
    image: busybox
    command: tail -f /dev/random
    volumes:
      - uploads:/var/uploads

 nginx:
    image: busybox
    command: tail -f /dev/random
    volumes:
      - uploads:/var/uploads
    depends_on:
      - "atom"

volumes:
  uploads:
    driver: "local"
```

Here they go up:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "t_default" with the default driver
Creating t_atom_1 ... done
Creating t_nginx_1 ... done
```

Here is your test, which works as expected:

```
$ docker-compose exec atom ls /var/
spool    uploads  www
```

Versions used:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build unknown
```

That is to say: I don't think the issue is in `docker-compose.yml`.
Maybe in the `Dockerfile`s? Or a bug in your `docker` / `docker-compose` versions?

Comment: thanks you're the hero of the day. actually, your answer helped me a lot as it confirmed that what I did was correct. After all the problem was some lines of code in a compose file. The entrypoint replaced files in my volume what explains the strange behavior! thank you!